# What is the difference between areas and "boxes" of a box in the box model

Tags: css

Regarding the margin, border, padding and contents of a box, what is the difference between *area* (margin, border, padding and content areas) and a *box* (margin box, border box, padding box and content box)?

For example, if they are the same thing, the *border box* is just an *area* **between** the *margin box* and the *padding box* whose thickness is determined by the `border-width` property ? Does the `border-box` value in the `box-sizing` property make `width` and `height` refer to this area?

Also, is the size of the margin box determined by the `margin`?

Comment: How is this question similar to another question? The other question was what a box model is, I'm already asking about the difference between "areas" (things like "margin area" and "padding area") and "boxes" (not the box that are generated from elements, made up of several "layers", but things like "margin-box" and "padding-box", with the suffix "-box"), if these terms mean the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-box-3/#box-model)

> Each box has a content area (which contains its content—text, descendant boxes, an image or other replaced element content, etc.) and optional **surrounding** padding, border, and margin **areas**; ...

and

> The perimeter of each of the four areas (content, padding, border, and margin) is called an edge, and each edge can be broken down into a top, right, bottom, and left side. Thus each **box** has four edges each composed of four sides:

So each of the margin, border, padding and content boxes is a *rectangle*, bounded by their edges.

On the other hand, while the content area is a rectangle, i.e. everything inside the content edges, the margin, border and padding areas are *rings* around the content area. That is, they are the space consumed between their respective edges and the edges of the box inside them.

> Does the border-box value in the box-sizing property make width and height refer to this area?

The border-box value is, as it says, the width and height refer to the dimensions of the border box, not the border area. i.e. the distances from the left edge to the right edge of the border, and from the top edge to the bottom edge of the border.

> Is the size of the margin box determined by the margin?

No, its determined by the size of the content area and the margin, border and padding values, noting of course that the margin values can be affected by margin collapse and adjustments to correct for over-constrainment.

Comment: I'm getting a little confused on the term "outer edge". In the documentation, the edge of the margin area is called the [outer edge](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-box-3/#outer-edge) and the edge of the content area is called the [inner edge](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-box-3/#inner-edge) of the entire box. Were you referring to this?

Comment: @CristianoMoraes - Fair enough, no I wasn't, and that was unclear. I just meant the _edge_ of each box - i.e. the locus of points that define the perimeter of each box furthest from the content box. I've changed my description to better match the specification.

Comment: In "That is, they are the space consumed between their respective edges and the edges of the box inside them.". You mean, for example, the margin area is the space consumed by the box (generated by the element), which is between the edge of the margin area and the edge of the box that is inside the area (the border edge)? Does each area include a box? How does this differ from a margin box, which includes the margin area and a border box?

Comment: @CristianoMoraes - "You mean, for example, the margin area is the space consumed by the box (generated by the element), which is between the edge of the margin area and the edge of the box that is inside the area (the border edge)?" - Yes, exactly that. So the margin box includes the border box, and the margin area excludes the border box.

Comment: Referring to margin, border, padding and content box as "rectangles" sounds a lot clearer, especially considering that the term "box" is already used for the actual box.

Answer (score 0):

1. Box is made of 4 edges (imaginery lines 0px wide) and the “area” of that box is what’s inside it.

   i.e. box width x box height = box area

E.g.
A Padding box surrounds the padding as well as the content.
The area will be the whole thing inside it (content area included).

2.

A. Border box is not area between margin and padding box, it is whole area inside the border box includes borders, padding, content.

B. Imagine a block with { border:2px; padding:10px; width:100px; } and some content.

box-sizing: content-box (default)
Results in a block with 100 + 10 + 10 + 2 + 2 = 124px wide box.

box-sizing: border-box
Results in a block with 100px wide, where content area is only 100 - 10 - 10 - 2 - 2 = 76px wide.